# append img in a div on click

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="imageToAppend" href="img/image.jpg">Click image to show</a>
<a class="imageToAppend" href="img/image1.jpg">Click image to show</a>
<a class="imageToAppend" href="img/image2.jpg">Click image to show</a>

<div class="appendHere"></div>
```

I want to show a image when I click on link, link contain the link to the image.
and append the image to `div`

I have a jQuery code but it shows all images, I just want to show the clicked link image

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.imageToAppend').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(".screenshot").prepend('<img src="<?php echo $photo->sourceImageFilePath; ?>" />');
});
});
});
```

Comment: U cant use PHP functions in client side.. Please provide the actual path to get better result.. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Deepak I am using this code on server side PHP

Comment: @AryanG: the click event is firing on client side and there in client side u cant execute ur php scripts. thats y the image is not showing. please try to hard cord image source `jQuery(".screenshot").prepend('<img src="<?php echo $photo->sourceImageFilePath; ?>" />');` here and check again if it working properly u can add dynamic image source by fetching it from server using an ajax call..

Comment: use some jquery plugins available http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

will save some time and effort as well: http://bit.ly/QKeBJh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the image you're trying to append is the image in the path of the href...

```
$('.imageToAppend').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('rel'),
        el = $('.appendHere');
    el.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        el.empty().text('Loading...').fadeIn().delay('400').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).empty();
            $('<img src="' + url + '" />').appendTo(el);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/TEPKd/

Comment: I also want to add loading animation  GIF. may I add `.slideDown` ??? or any effective effect

Comment: Of course you can, I've edited my answer and my fiddle for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function){
 $('a.imageToAppend').click(function(e){
  var currentLink=$(this);

  $('#appendHere').empty() // remove existing img/html, if added already
  //generate image tag on fly and assign src from current anchor clicked and add to div
  $('<img />').attr("src",$(currentLink).attr("href")).appendTo($('#appendHere'));
  e.preventDefault();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Deepak mentions, you can't evaluate PHP on the client-side, however you could read the filename from the

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('.imageToAppend').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');   //$this will be the <a> clicked
    jQuery(".screenshot").prepend('<img src="'+src+'"/>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imageToAppend').click(function(e){  
    $(".appendHere").append(this);
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/xmt8A/)

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
$(function(){
    $('.imageToAppend').click(function(e){
        var img = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.appendHere').prepend($('<img/>')
                      .attr('src', img));      
    });
})
```